# Is it possible to get the key of a translated string on laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have on resources/lang/fr_FR.json, resources/lang/en_US.json etc there I have all keys on spanish and his value on the desired language.

I'm trying to translate the URL incoming, for example if I click on "contacto" if I'm on spanish language and I siwtch to english it works fine because I have the key contacto registered, but if I'm in english I have "contact" and I don't have this key to translate in.

Thath's the function that changes the url locale

```
  public function setLocale($locale, $desiredLocale)
    {
        $previousUrl = explode("/", url()->previous());
        $newUrl = array();

        foreach ($previousUrl as $segment) {
            $translatedSegment =  __($segment, [], $desiredLocale);
            array_push($newUrl, $translatedSegment);
        }
        $uri = implode("/", $newUrl);
        $uri = str_ireplace($locale, $desiredLocale, $uri);


        return redirect($uri, 301);
    }
```

EDIT: What I want to achieve

I have on navbar a dropdown with the languages, es, fr, eng, for example

I'm on `http://localhost/laravel-project/public/es_ES/inicio`, then I click on my dropdown the language eng and it send me to this route:

```
<a class="dropdown-item" href="{{route('setLocale', ['desiredLocale' => $key])}}">eng</a>
```

My locale route:

```
//Language swap
Route::get('/language/{desiredLocale}', 'LocaleController@setLocale')->name('setLocale');
```

and my localeController is the function that I showed up, (the $locale variable comes from a middleware so is setted on url::default)

It should redirect me to `http://localhost/laravel-project/public/en_US/home`

Then since on my web.php I have:

```
Route::get(__('inicio'), function () {
    return view('pages.home.index');
})->name('inicio');
```

It would search on my en_US.json the word and the route and it will exist:

```
{
    "inicio": "home",
}
```

Comment: Yes, but isn't it better to change it bases on something else? This sound like a workaround that's going to be more work. I can help think out a better solution if you can provide me information where the user is coming from, where he has to go etc.

Comment: @Thomas I edited my question so you can understand better what I want to achieve

Comment: cant see what you're trying to do. Are the urls to be defined by the translation files?

Comment: @Flame yes, also I edited again so you can understand better, the short problem is translate routes with translation files